# Can I connect this display(ER-TFTM101-1) to Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: raspberry-pi, display, raspberry-pi4

I'm planning to make Smart Mirror using a 10.1-inch display.
While I searched display to use I found this display:
https://www.buydisplay.com/serial-spi-i2c-10-1-inch-tft-lcd-module-dislay-w-ra8876-optl-touch-panel
(ER-TFTM101-1)

But I don't know if this display is compatible with Raspberry Pi 4.

Here is datasheet:
https://www.buydisplay.com/download/manual/ER-TFTM101-1_Datasheet.pdf

Q1. Can I connect this display(ER-TFTM101-1) to Raspberry Pi 4?

Q2. If can connect, how to connect? Do I need to purchase additional products?